# Make a simple method work in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, view, controller, ruby-on-rails-5

REFORMULATED FOR MORE INFO

I'll be rather short. As a newbie, that's the error I am getting while developing my rails app:

```
param is missing or the value is empty: task
```

The error highlights:

```
def task_params
  params.require(:task).permit(:name, :description, :deadline, :status, :pdf, :done)
end
```

It happens **when I click the button 'Mark as done'** I'm creating.

Here follows the code:

app/views/tasks/index.html.erb:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Tasks</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Time</th>
      <th>Ready?</th>
      <th colspan="10"></th>
     </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @tasks.each do |task| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= task.name %></td>
        <td><%= task.description %></td>
        .
        .
        .
        <td><%= (link_to 'Mark done', task_path(task, done: true), method: :PUT) %></td>
       </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>
```

app/controllers/tasks_controller.rb:

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_task, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /tasks
  # GET /tasks.json
  def index
    @tasks = Task.all
  end

  # GET /tasks/1
  # GET /tasks/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /tasks/new
  def new
    @task = Task.new
  end

  # GET /tasks/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /tasks
  # POST /tasks.json
  def create
    @task = Task.new(task_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @task.save
        format.html { redirect_to @task, notice: 'Task was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @task   }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /tasks/1
  # PATCH/PUT /tasks/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @task.update(task_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @task, notice: 'Task was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @task }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end 

  # DELETE /tasks/1
  # DELETE /tasks/1.json
  def destroy
    @task.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to tasks_url, notice: 'Task was    successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
     end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_task
      @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def task_params
      params.require(:task).permit(:name, :description, :deadline, :status, :pdf, :done)
    end

end
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You have a scope problem on your hands. You're not setting `@task` in your `setdone` method. You might have defined `@task` in some other method, but its scope doesn't extend to `setdone`.

Comment: Okay, I understand the problem, but as a rails newbie, how do I fix that? How do I set @task ?

Comment: @VictorSprengel, when you are using an instance variable too often, and if it is usually fetched the same way, you can add a `before_action` in your controller, perhaps: `before_action :set_task`, and then define that private method in you controller: `def set_task`, and inside that method just set your `@task` variable, perhaps with `@task = Task.find(params[:id])`. It really all depends on how you're doing things.

Comment: @fanta I'm using the before_action :set_task now and I wrote the set_task method following a guide. My problem now is that, using the code provided in the answer, I'm getting "Couldn't find Task with 'id'=". How can I fix that, looking at the code I provided? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show rake routes?

Answer (score 1):

since you've done this in controller as you said in command

```
before_action :set_task

def set_task
 @task = Task.find(params[:id)
end
```

you should simply be able to do :

```
<td><%= 'Mark as done', tasks_setdone_path(task), method: :post %></td>
```

and not `<td><%= 'Mark as done', tasks_setdone_path(task), method: :post %></td>`

'@' represent instance variable accessible from controller AND template.

Another thing is that your action controller will require a respond (html or json).

Now that you answer is given, here is the proper way to do it.

```
task_path(@task, done: true), method: :PUT
```

POST is use for creation where PUT is use for updating an object.

Comment: Sorry about letting the post die for 10 days, been really busy with other stuff. Thank you for the thorough answer, now I'm looking to do it the proper way. I edited my question with how it looks now and the new error message.

Comment: sorry man but post your controller and the view because your code looks like a mess and we can't help you properly that way

Comment: There you go. Question reformulated with all info.

Comment: task_path(@task, {task: {done: true}}), method: :PUT

Comment: look at pry gem for debug stuff